# Xamarin VS 2017 Pro webView Issue - App builds and runs first time but not after 1st run. Have to Repair VS to run again

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, webview

thanks for reading!  I’m a DB guy with a little front-end dev experience in Visual Studio (mostly DB guy though).  I’m trying to create a Xamarin cross-platform mobile app to use a WebView to display my girlfriends non-profit cat rescue organization.  I’m using Visual Studio 2017 Professional 15.9.12.  My code for the WebView is below.  Currently on a fresh install or repair of VS, the app will build and run beautifully minus some formatting issues.  The menu control and tabs in the emulator work and all is great!  However, every time I stop the app and then try to rebuild and run again, the emulator goes to a black screen and eventually will not respond and must be shut down.  The build shows successful, but the app just won’t start within the emulator, I just get the black screen.  If I do a repair of VS and reboot my machine, I can restart VS and the app will build and run perfectly on the first attempt.  But if I close the app and then rerun it, it will never display on the emulator.  It says build completed but all I get is the black screen.  I’ve read a few comments about this (a couple on here) and it may still be an issue in VS but some folks have found work arounds, but they don’t work for me, only a VS repair works so far and it’s only good for one time, and then I must repair again.  I’ve tried the following suggestions that I found online:

-Clean and rebuild solution.  This does not work for me.

-Unchecked “Use Shared Runtime” in the Android Properties section.  No change for me.

-Tried adding additional “Suggested Architectures” of x86 and x86_64 in the Advanced section of the Android Properties section.  This didn’t change anything.

I’ve tried the 3 above solutions independently as well as together and those changes didn’t change the behavior for my app.  After an initial build and run after a VS repair, the app will run perfectly.  But once I close the app and try to rerun it the app just goes to black screen and VS displays “Deploying to Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo” for a minute or so.  That status changes to Ready eventually but then when I try to interact with the black screen app it starts Not Responding and eventually shuts down.

Has anyone had to deal with this issue before or possibly have any suggestions as to what might be the resolution?  Thanks to everyone in advance!!  BTW, I can provide print screens of anything detailed if need.  Thanks again!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            Label header = new Label
            {
                Text = "WebView",
                FontSize = 50,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            WebView = new WebView()
            {
                Source = new UrlWebViewSource
                {
                    Url = "https://nashvillecatrescue.org/",
                },
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            // Build the page.
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    //header,
                    webView
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if repair fixes the problem, it is not a code issue, but an environment problem with your emulator.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I wasn't thinking it was a code problem but I wanted to be thorough and post my code just to share how simple it was (and not likely a code problem).  All the forums and chats I've come across indicated an issue with a known bug in VS but several of the forums had work-arounds, such as I provided in my original post.  Regardless of environment issue, code issue, known bug, etc, I am still hoping for a resolution or work-around for this.  Any detailed suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: you can submit a bug report directly from VS

Comment: I'm not 100% certain it's a bug though honestly.  I've only been able to find 2 forums discussing something very similar to my issue (where the emulator did work once), one being the URL below.  And in each forum, someone suggested a work-around that worked for that user but those work-arounds did not work for me.  The "known bug" I mentioned was from several posts I came across where the user could not ever get the emulator to work which is slightly different from my issue as my emulator works initially once but then not again.  So I'd like to research and seek advice before reporting a bug.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reason this shouldn't be working. Have you tried the same with VS 2019? You can share your code if you like on Github, and we can try it for you.

Comment: VS 2017 only has old versions of Xamarin that may run into issues with newer versions of the emulators. Xamarin is not getting updated in VS 2017 anymore (except for security issues), so to get the latest versions of Xamarin you need to upgrade to VS 2019. And I would recommend doing so. Sometimes the Xamarin tools need to be modified to work with updated third party tools from Google (Android) and Apple, so the Android emulators can get updated and you may need to use an updated Xamarin to match.

Comment: Saamer, jgoldberger, thanks for the suggestion to upgrade to VS 2019.  I will give that a shot and let you guys know if I still have this issue.  Thanks guys!

Comment: I installed VS 2019 and have moved the code into a blank Xamarin project.  I thought all was good and the emulator was going to work but I'm still having issues with the emulator and am now getting the "ADB1000: Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: secure_mkdirs failed: No such file or directory  …" error.  The project builds successfully but the emulator is now displaying "Decryption Unsuccessful" when I run the app.  I'm continuing to investigate this new issue.

Comment: I was able to get the emulator to run by repairing the Android SDK and doing some updates.  However, I also have to do a factory reset on Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo each time I run the emulator but at least it's working now.  The app won't start and is instead just going to a blank white screen but I think I'm making progress and will research this new issue.  I believe this thread can be closed since I'm now dealing with separate issues.  Thanks to everyone for listening and helping!